# a highlight command resets previously declared highlights

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to tune the highlighting in my vim and I'm trying to set some syntax groups via the `match` command and highlight them in my `vimrc` file, because those groups are generic and do not belong to any particular language syntax file.

But my approach works only for a single highlighting, as soon as I add another instance of a `highlight/match` pair the previously declared ones do not work, only the last one works until I add another `highlight/match`.

This is the code (the relevant part) of my vimrc.
This example works:

```
hi NewLineWin ctermfg=248 guifg=#999999
match NewLineWin /\r\n/
```

And this doesn't (only the last pair of `hi/match` does):

```
hi NewLineWin ctermfg=248 guifg=#999999
match NewLineWin /\r\n/
hi WhiteSpaceChar ctermfg=252 guifg=#999999
match WhiteSpaceChar / /
```

Can anyone help me with this, how to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `:help :match`

> Highlighting matches using :match are limited to three
>   matches (aside from :match, :2match and :3match are
>   available). matchadd() does not have this limitation and in
>   addition makes it possible to prioritize matches.

So you can use:

```
hi NewLineWin ctermfg=248 guifg=#999999
match NewLineWin /\r\n/
hi WhiteSpaceChar ctermfg=252 guifg=#999999
2match WhiteSpaceChar / /
```

Or:

```
hi NewLineWin ctermfg=248 guifg=#999999
match NewLineWin /\r\n/
hi WhiteSpaceChar ctermfg=252 guifg=#999999
call matchadd("WhiteSpaceChar", " ")
```

`matchadd()` also allows further flexibility, such as deleting or prioritising matches. See `:help matchadd()` for more details.

Alternatively, look into syntax highlighting: `:help syntax`

Answer (score 3):

What about using the

> :sy[ntax] match {group-name} [{options}] [excludenl] {pattern}
>   [{options}]

```
:hi NewLineWin ctermfg=248 guifg=#999999
:syntax match NewLineWin /\r\n/
:hi WhiteSpaceChar ctermfg=252 guifg=#999999
:syntax match WhiteSpaceChar / /
```

You can use any number of such match...